# Identifying bad fibers of an elliptic surface given by a pencil of cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, blowup

I know that every rational elliptic surface is given by the blowup of the $9$ points of intersection of two cubics in $\Bbb{P}^2$ (at least one of them being smooth).

Take for example the cubics $C_1,C_2\subset\Bbb{P^2}$ such that $C_1$ is given by $yz^2-x(x^2-z^2)=0$ and $C_2$ is the triple line $3L$ where $L:y=0$, and let $\pi:X\to \Bbb{P}^1$ be the elliptic surface generated by them.

(this is just a particular example I'm curious about, but any other will be fine)

What I'm trying to do is to identify all singular fibres of $\pi$ and classify them by their Kodaira symbols.

I know how to do that given the Weierstrass equation for the surface, but I don't know how to find it here.

I've stumbled upon [this](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/file/RIMS1800.pdf) nice material which gave me the impression that these things can be treated geometrically, with actual pictures, but I don't understand how the constructions are made.

In the particular example I gave, I don't know what happens to the triple line after the blowup and what information this will give about the bad fibers. Even in simpler cases, like when $C_1, C_2$ meet in $9$ different points, I do see what happens in after blowing up, but I still don't understand what that tells me about the bad fibres.

I wish I could understand this geometric approach, since this way it would be interesting to come up with other different possibilities for $C_1,C_2$ and see what happens.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The triple line should be a fiber in and of itself, just a $\mathbb P^1$ with multiplicity $3$. If you want your surface to only have fibers with simple multiplicity, you can fix this as follows: let $p \in \mathbb P^1$ be the point such that $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is the triple line, and let $f:C \to \mathbb P^1$ be a triple cover totally ramified over $p$. Then the fiber product $X \times_{\mathbb P^1} C$ is an elliptic surface over $C$, and the fiber over $f^{-1}(p)$ now has multiplicity $1$. To understand what happens to the fiber itself, note that the sections of $\pi$ induce branch points.

Comment: Maybe this is too computational, but it looks like your pencil is given by $C_t: y^2 - (x^3 - x) + t y^3$ where $t$ is the coordinate on the base $\mathbb{P}^1$. I managed to find a Weierstrass model and rescaling gives the integral model $E: y^2 = x^3 - 16 x + 64 t^2$. Now you should be able to find the bad places by factoring the discriminant and determine the Kodaira symbols using Tate's algorithm.